# I am unable to solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')", trying to create filter cascade buttons

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I have tried various solutions but I am not able to fix it. Can anyone help me please ? I am trying to create buttons where buttons in column B are filtered by clicking on buttons in column A. Right now, the buttons are getting rendered in the left menu (warehouses). But when I click on a warehouse, the respective paintings in the right column (buttons) dont render and I get the below error.

```
const Separator = () => {
  // Function Component

  // for warehouse - this works
  const [warehouseList, setWarehouseList] = useState([]);

  // export component

  useEffect(() => {
    // right when the Separator list renders, we run this function

    axios
      .get(API_BASE_URL)
      .then((res) => {
        setWarehouseList(res.data);
        console.log("printing warehouses -- ");
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.res));
  }, []); // this should return all the warehouses

  // const [_id, setID] = useState([warehouseList._id]);

  const [relatedPaintings, setRelatedPaintings] = useState([warehouseList._id]); // passing all warehouses with ids

  //const get_id = useRef(relatedPaintings._id);

  const paintingButtonItems = [
    ...new Set(
      relatedPaintings._id.map((relatedPaintings) => relatedPaintings.data)
    ),
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    // right when the Separator list renders, we run this function

    //  const id = get_id;

    axios
      .get(API_BASE_URL + "/" + relatedPaintings)
      .then((res) => {
        setRelatedPaintings(res.data);
        console.log("printing paintings ");
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.res));
  }, [relatedPaintings]); // only return painting for specific warehouse

  return (
    // return JSX

    <>
      <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="adjustRow">
            <td>
              <ListGroup className="listWidth">
                <ListGroup.Item action variant="warning">
                  {" "}
                  <strong> Warehouses </strong>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>

              {warehouseList.map((warehouse) => {
                return <Warehouse key={warehouse._id} warehouse={warehouse} />;
              })}
            </td>
            <td id="adjustTD">
              <ListGroup className="listWidth">
                <ListGroup.Item action variant="warning">
                  {" "}
                  <strong> Paintings </strong>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>

              {
                (paintingButtonItems || []).map((relatedPaintings, id) => {
                  return (
                    <Painting
                      key={relatedPaintings.id}
                      value={relatedPaintings}
                    />
                  );
                })
                //paintingList.map(painting => <Painting warehouse={Warehouse._id} painting={painting}/>)         // LOGIC FOR POPULATING THIS IS UP THERE
              }
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Separator;
```

Comment: `useState([warehouseList._id]); // passing all warehouses with ids` it doesn't do what you described

Comment: Hey Konrad. How can I fix it ?

Comment: `useState(warehouseList.map(item => item._id))`, but making dependent states like that will cause more errors, you should have only one state

Comment: It is not clear to me Konrad. You want me to write - useState(warehouseList._id] instead of  useState([warehouseList._id]) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the map property of an undefined value. This is likely happening because the value of relatedPaintings is undefined when you are trying to access it.

You can fix this by making sure that relatedPaintings is defined before trying to access its map property. You can do this by using a condition like so:

```
if (relatedPaintings) {
  // access the map property here
}
```

Comment: Hu! Mohamed. Thanks for your comment. But its still not working. Still gives the same error. Is the rest of my code right ?